# after update right half of keyboard converted to num keys u-4, j-1, m-0 so on

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

Hi i am using below after update right half of keyboard converted to num keys u-4, j-1, m-0 so on 
issue started after running update on 15 dec 2016
please help

```
LENOVO3000-V200 Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic i686 (32 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
Desktop: MATE 1.12.1 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1)
Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine: System: LENOVO (portable) product: 07648DJ v: LENOVO3000 V200
Mobo: LENOVO model: INVALID
Bios: LENOVO v: 65ET58WW (0.09 ) date: 02/01/2008
CPU: Dual core Intel Core2 Duo T8100 (-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 8399
clock speeds: max: 2101 MHz 1: 1600 MHz 2: 1600 MHz
Graphics: Card: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
bus-ID: 00:02.0
Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
Resolution: 1280x800@60.00hz
GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2
GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio: Card Intel 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-53-generic
Network: Card-1: Broadcom NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express
driver: tg3 v: 3.137 bus-ID: 05:00.0
IF: enp5s0 state: down mac: 00:0a:e4:cf:a2:8e
Card-2: Intel PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
driver: iwl4965 v: in-tree: bus-ID: 06:00.0
IF: wlp6s0 state: up mac: 00:1f:3b:c6:a1:7b
Drives: HDD Total Size: 120.0GB (11.2% used)
ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MK1246GS size: 120.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 108G used: 11G (11%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0
ID-2: /boot size: 472M used: 343M (77%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda1
ID-3: swap-1 size: 1.60GB used: 0.24GB (15%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-2
RAID: No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors: None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured?
Info: Processes: 217 Uptime: 19 min Memory: 1030.1/1497.9MB
Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
Client: Shell (bash 4.3.461) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: By the way My :/* and left control key does not work from the day I installed MATE 16.04
Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Is Num Lock on?

Answer (score 0):

Check your NUM lock key.  That controls whether that section of the keyboard is treated as a keypad.  If the NUM lock key is on the keys below the 7,8 and 9 become the key pad keys instead of the alpha keys on keyboards without an actual keypad section.  Your symptoms are those of having the NUM lock key on. Some keyboards have a light when the NUM lock key is on, but some don't.  Some keyboards will have the NUM lock as a function shift of another key, like the Scrl lock.  The key will toggle the keyboard, so type it once to shift back to the alpha keyboard.